# How to define gradient function for this op in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to implement a new op in tensorflow, there are three input tensors and two output tensors, as follows (some codes are ignored due to unrelated to this question):

```
REGISTER_OP("MyNewFuncOp")
    .Attr("alpha: float = 1.0")
    .Attr("beta: float = 1.0")
    .Attr("debug: bool = false")
    .Input("input1: float32")
    .Input("input2: float32")
    .Input("input3: float32")
    .Output("output1: float32")
    .Output("output2: float32")
    .SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
      c->set_output(0, c->input(0));
      c->set_output(1, c->input(1));
      return Status::OK();
    });

class MyNewFuncOp : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit MyNewFuncOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {
   // some staffs
   ...
  }
 void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
   // some staffs
   ...
   Tensor* output_tensor1 = NULL;
   OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, TensorShape({height, width, channels}),
                                                 &output_tensor1));
   Tensor* output_tensor2 = NULL;
   OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(1, TensorShape({height, width, channels}),
                                                 &output_tensor2));

 // some other staffs
 ...
 }
```

And the gradient registration is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
custom_module = tf.load_op_library('MyNewFunc.so')

@ops.RegisterGradient("MyNewFun")
def _MyNewFun_grad(op, grad1, grad2):
    input3 = op.inputs[2]
    return [grad1, grad2, tf.zeros_like(input3)]
```

But this gradient function seems wrong from my experiments, it can run OK, but after running the `grads = opt.compute_gradients(total_loss)` in build training operator, this op will generate wrong results. But this op can run OK and also generate correct results in evaluation status (no training, i.e., no gradient computation). So I realize this gradient function may be wrong. I've read this page in official documents https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/docs_src/extend/adding_an_op.md#implement-gradient. In fact, in this op, I just want the top errors arrived the two output tensors (`output1` and `output2`) are directly copied(back-propagated) to the first two input tensors (i.e., `input1` and `input2`).

How could I implement the correct gradient function for this op? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
custom_module = tf.load_op_library('MyNewFunc.so')

@ops.RegisterGradient("MyNewFun")
def _MyNewFun_grad(_, *grads):
    return list(grads) + [None]
```

Comment: Nice. Additionally, if you want your op to be usable for training via the C++ API (i.e. for use in other language bindings), you can add C++ gradients by following these instructions: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/cc/gradients/README.md

Comment: Hi,@suharshs, thanks a lot for your kind suggestion!